# Notepad++ replace all ( | ) this char with comma

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
<Etiketler>banko sistem nedir|normal sistemle banko sistem arasındaki fark nedir|sistem|sistem kazançlı mıdır|sistem nasıl oynanır|sistem ne işe yarar|sistem nedir|sistem sıfır nasıl oynanır | bahiskritik.com </Etiketler>
```

i have this case in my xml file. and i try raplace with this

```
<Etiketler>(.*?)[\|](.*?)<\/Etiketler\>
```

with this

```
<Etiketler>$1 , $2</Etiketler>
```

but only changing first " | " case. Can you please help me?

Comment: why not just find -> replace all '|' to ' , ' (point being, I don't see the need for a regex)

Comment: becouse file too big. and < img > case have same "|" char. i just want to change in < Etiketler> case. understand?

Comment: [you can't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/984407)

Comment: i did use all. but only changing first | char. like this. 

<Etiketler>banko sistem nedir "," normal sistemle banko sistem arasındaki fark nedir|sistem|sistem kazançlı mıdır|sistem nasıl oynanır|sistem ne işe yarar|sistem nedir|sistem sıfır nasıl oynanır | bahiskritik.com </Etiketler>

Comment: I'm saying you're going about your problem the wrong way.  Don't use a regex to modify html.  Use an html parser then find and replace the characters like I mentioned above.

Comment: If you have no nested tags inside the `Etiketler` tag, you can use 
`(?:\G(?!^)|<Etiketler>)[^|<]*?\K\|` Notepad++ regex.